# Sluggish graphics in 16.04, Intel card

Tags: 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10. Most everything is working fine, except for playing Steam games. All games, including those that worked without any problems on windows, run extraordinarily slowly to the degree that they are unplayable.

I am using an Aspire M5-481PT with a 3rd generation Intel corporation graphics controller.

Is there anything I can/should do?